# Log4Net with ASP.NET Core 2.2 to write to a File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net, asp.net-core-2.2

In my ASP.NET Core 2.2 application I installed [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore)

in startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;
        }
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
    ....
    .....
      _logger.LogInformation("Added TodoRepository to services");
    .....
    .....
        }

      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
                UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<Role> roleManager,
                ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
     ....
     loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
     ....

    }
```

In my Home controller

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Home Index page");
            _logger.LogWarning("Home Index page");
            _logger.LogError("Home Index page");
            _logger.LogDebug("Home Index page");
            return View();
        }
```

I see the logs showing up in Visual Studio Output window, but this is not writing to any files.

log4net.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <file value="C:\Temp\WebAppFolder" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd.'txt'"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level App  %newline %message %newline %newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Your `datePattern` value seems malformed. Shouldn't have that `.txt` in there, should it? Also, I think you need to fill out the `file` value with the full path of the text file you want to log to.

Comment: That was it. <file value="C:\\Temp\\WebAppFolder\\web-" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>

Comment: I've just added that as an answer, mind accepting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `datePattern` value seems malformed. Shouldn't have that `.txt` in there. Also, you need to fill out the `file` value with the full path of the text file you want to log to.

Comment: Does it have to be the full path? I'm having trouble getting it to log in file in a .net core 3 app hosted in Azure app service